# Rendering With conditions in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I applying if else statement to display different things based on **if firestore is ready and the user is logged in**, but the **firebase.auth.uid** is coming back undefined even it is correctly hooked to the store, and I am stuck at the loading block.

Dashboard.js:

```
       ...
        componentDidMount() {
    console.log("our props", this.props.firebase.auth.uid)
  }

        render() {
            const { fireStore, firebase } = this.props;


            if(fireStore && firebase.auth.uid){
            return (
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <BoardList boards={fireStore} />
                </div>
              </div>
            )} else {
              return(
                <div style={{ display: 'flex',flex:1 ,flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>

                  <SelfBuildingSquareSpinner color={Color.bgColor} style={{marginTop: '5em'}} />
                  <div style={{textAlign:"center", marginTop: '5em'}}>Welcome to Scrum Board</div>
                </div>
              )
            }
          } 
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      console.log("our state from dashboard ",state);
      return {
        scrumBoard: state.scrumBoard,
        fireStore: state.fireStore.ordered.scrumboards,
        firebase: state.firebase,
        users: state.users
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        fetchData : () => dispatch(fetchData()),
      }
    }

    export default compose(
      connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
      ),
      firestoreConnect([{ collection: "scrumboards" },{collection: "users"}])
    )(Dashboard);
```

this.props.firebase.auth.uid is undefined and i am stuck in the second block.
&& my console shows that both firebase and firestore are populated with data:

[image]

I am thinking this is component life cycle issue where, this dashboard component is loaded before store has values but I think once it is populated it should render boardlist component.

Comment: can you put a `console.log(this.props)` command in the render function pls?

Comment: @gazdagergo I am getting undefined as a result

Comment: but in line 42 it communicates that `mapStateToProps` has been called and props has been mapped and passed to the component 4 times. Why didn't those props available in render? I understand that within `componentDidMount` it gives `undefined` as it is called at the very beginning only. But render is called every time, unless a `shouldComponentUpdate` is set to `false`.

Comment: @gazdagergo I didn't set shouldComponentUpdate to false or anything and managed to switch HOC's order and it worked!

Comment: cool, good to know 

Answer (score 0):

Switching the order of the HOC in compose solved this issue!!!
frankly I don't understand why for now... but if you ever come across this problem I hope this helps.
Your code should be like so:

```
...
export default compose(
      firestoreConnect([{ collection: "scrumboards" },{collection: "users"}]),
      connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
      )
    )(Dashboard);
```